# Select one row, and if not exist, a different one

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is the situation.

Imagine a table with a few columns:

| ID | Name | Language | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | ES | ... |
| 2 | Bob | EN | ... |
| 3 | Bob | DE | ... |
| 4 | Bill | EN | ... |
| 5 | Jack | EN | ... |
| 6 | Jack | DE | ... |
| 7 | Jack | ES | ... |

Given a specific language, I want to select all the IDs. If the language is not available, I want to default to EN.
So as an example, of I select for ES, I want to get:

| ID | Name | Language | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | ES | ... |
| 4 | Bill | EN | ... |
| 7 | Jack | ES | ... |

And if I select for EN I want to get:

| ID | Name | Language | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Bob | EN | ... |
| 4 | Bill | EN | ... |
| 5 | Jack | EN | ... |

There can be up to 10 different languages, and in total there is close to 500k lines. There is about 90k different names.

For now I found one option using COALESCE, but this requires 2 queries for every line. Somelike:

```
SELECT COALESCE (
  (SELECT ..... WHERE language = 'ES'),
  (SELECT ..... WHERE language = 'EN')
)
```

But is there a more efficient way to do that? Something like:
SELECT ..... WHERE language = ('ES' AND IF NOT EXIST THEN 'EN).

Thanks.

**Edit:**
The COALESCE approach doesn't work. First, it can return only one column and second, it can return only one line.

Comment: left join name with language, coalesce the language to EN.

Comment: @JorgeCampos do you have an example?

Comment: Something along these lines (two sub queries, but instead of inner you do a left join) https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005314/460557

Comment: Actual table definitions showing data types and constraints, and your version of Postgres would be instrumental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I missed the postgreSQL tag -- the original answer was in MS SQL. I downloaded PostgreSQL and adapted it.

Typically I join to a users table and have simulated that in this response.

Get all users, connect them to the language table and then case statement the fall back if the desired language is missing. You could coalesce if you prefer.

```
-- Demo Data
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE tmp_Users (Name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO tmp_Users
VALUES 
    ('Bob'),
    ('Bill'),
    ('Jack');

CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE tmp_langs (Id int, Name varchar(50), Language varchar(2));
INSERT INTO tmp_langs
VALUES
    (1, 'Bob', 'ES'),
    (2, 'Bob', 'EN'),
    (3, 'Bob', 'DE'),
    (4, 'Bill', 'EN'),
    (5, 'Jack', 'EN'),
    (6, 'Jack', 'DE'),  
    (7, 'Jack', 'ES');


    
SELECT 
    u.Name,
    CASE
        WHEN sl.Language IS NOT null THEN sl.Language
        ELSE dl.Language -- this assumes every entry has an EN default
    END use_language
FROM tmp_Users u
LEFT JOIN tmp_langs AS sl --selectedLanguage
    on sl.Language = 'ES' AND u.Name = sl.Name -- join on your user ids
LEFT JOIN tmp_langs AS dl --defaultLanguage
    on dl.Language = 'EN' AND u.Name = dl.Name;
```

With ES

| Name | use_language |
| --- | --- |
| bob | ES |
| Bill | EN |
| Jack | ES |

WITH EN

| Name | use_language |
| --- | --- |
| bob | EN |
| Bill | EN |
| Jack | EN |

== With just the table as I see it in your question ==

Here you grab everyone's default, then go back and union everyone with EN default that doesn't have the selected language.

```
SELECT
    l.Id,
    l.Name,
    l.Language
FROM tmp_langs l
WHERE l.Language = 'EN'
UNION
SELECT
    dl.Id,
    dl.Name,
    dl.Language
FROM tmp_langs dl -- default language
WHERE dl.Language = 'EN'
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tmp_langs l WHERE l.Language = 'ES' AND l.Name = dl.Name )
ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: Wow! Ok. THAT is exactly what I was looking for! Syntax seems to be a little bit different for me, but at the end I get the expected result! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed the postgresql -- answered with MS SQL

Comment: An honest mistake. But the answer is not helpful for Postgres. Shouldn't be accepted.

Comment: @jmspaggi If you remove the accepted mark, I can delete the answer. I went to https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and tried the PostgreSQL by Frank Heikens works for the sample I tried. Going forward, I'll try to scan the tags better. BTW, that distinct on expression is nice. -- Servus

Comment: This answer is much more efficient than using `DISTINCT ON` with a custom `ORDER BY`, just needs the syntax cleaning up for Postgres. Do not delete it.

Comment: @Charlieface based on your input, I downloaded Postgresql and adapted the answer, so that it at least works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DISTINCT ON for this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (name)
    id
    , name
    , language
 FROM t1
 ORDER BY name
        , language = 'ES' DESC -- this one is your preference
        , language = 'EN' DESC -- default
        , id;
```

Comment: I like the idea! But there is 2 things. The ES can be generic :-/ So should be more like everything but EN. Also, when I try to with " = 'ES' DESC " I get an error saying that it's not matching my DISTINCT ON clause. The ORDER BY with just language works, but obviously returns too mane rows.

Comment: @jmspaggi: This is the *much* better answer. *"So should be more like everything but EN."* is confusing. Set your question straight if it's misleading. The error you report must come from a different query. `DISTINCT ON (name)` in this query only demands `name` as leading `ORDER BY` expression. [Basics here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860).

Comment: @jmspaggi You must have changed the query and made a mistake. We can only guess

Answer (score 1):

**Main Answer**

For the sake of simulating / replicating the problem, I created the following temporary tables:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE langs (id INT, name VARCHAR(25), lang CHAR(2));
INSERT INTO langs
VALUES
    (1, 'Bob', 'ES'),
    (2, 'Bob', 'EN'),
    (3, 'Bob', 'DE'),
    (4, 'Bill', 'EN'),
    (5, 'Jack', 'EN'),
    (6, 'Jack', 'DE'),  
    (7, 'Jack', 'ES');

CREATE TEMP TABLE users (name VARCHAR(25));
INSERT INTO users
VALUES 
    ('Bob'),
    ('Bill'),
    ('Jack');
```

We perform the filter operation at least twice: once for the selected language and once of the default language. Therefore, I think it makes sense to create a function instead of repeating the query over and over:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION filter_by_lang(selected_lang CHAR(2))
RETURNS SETOF langs AS $$
    SELECT * FROM langs WHERE lang = selected_lang
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT
    COALESCE(s.id, d.id) AS id,
    u.name,
    COALESCE(s.lang, d.lang) AS lang
FROM users AS u
    LEFT JOIN filter_by_lang('ES') AS s ON u.name = s.name
    LEFT JOIN filter_by_lang('EN') AS d ON u.name = d.name;
```

COALESCE returns the first non NULL value. In the context of our problem, it return the first available id and language for a particular user.

**Bonus**

Let's say that there are two default languages. Thus if the person does not speak the selected language or the first default language, show the second default language. Using the same approach:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION filter_by_lang(selected_lang CHAR(2))
RETURNS SETOF langs AS $$
    SELECT * FROM langs WHERE lang = selected_lang
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

SELECT
    COALESCE(s.id, d1.id, d2.id) AS id,
    u.name,
    COALESCE(s.lang, d1.lang, d2.lang) AS lang
FROM users AS u
    LEFT JOIN filter_by_lang('ES') AS s ON u.name = s.name
    LEFT JOIN filter_by_lang('EN') AS d1 ON u.name = d1.name
    LEFT JOIN filter_by_lang('DE') AS d2 ON u.name = d2.name
```

By creating a function, we save ourself from repetitive writing and we make the query much more readable.